# For what values of $t$(if any) do $(2, 1, 1), (2, t, 2t)$ span $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb R^3$ such that

$2a + 2b = x$

$a + tb = y$

$a + 2tb = z$

So,

$a = \frac {(x – 2b)}{2}$

$b = \frac {(y – a)}{t}$

Then,

$ \frac {(x – 2b)}{2}(2, 1, 1) + \frac{(y – a)}{t}(2, t, 2t)$

$ = (x – 2b, \frac {(x – 2b)}{2}, \frac {(x – 2b)}{2}) + (\frac{2y -2a}{t}, y – a, 2y – 2a)$

$= (2a, a, a) + (2b, tb, 2tb)$

$= (2 + 2b, a + tb, a + 2tb)$

$= (x, y, z)$

From here, how can we show that $t$ is not allowed to vary?

I tried this below:

Since $b = \frac {(y – a)}{t}$, we have that $t \neq 0$. Suppose $t = p > 0$. Then $(2 + 2b, a + tb, a + 2tb) = (2 + 2b, a + pb, a + 2pb) \neq (x, y, z)$. Let $t = q < 0.$ Then $(2 + 2b, a + tb, a + 2tb) = (2 + qb, a + qb, a + 2qb) \neq (x, y, z)$.

Comment: $2$ vectors can never span a $3$-dimensional space (like $\Bbb R^3$).  So you can tell straight off the bat that no value $t$ will do.

Comment: @ Bye_World, I was hoping that fact would somehow break the little algebra I did. So that's what I am trying to do.

Comment: You divide by the unknown $t$, which may be $0$. So you should distinguish between the cases $t = 0$ and $t \neq 0$.

Comment: How will you span, say (1,0,0) ?

Comment: OK here's a general method you can use.  Assume you know some basis $\mathcal B$ for your vector space $V$ (you *do* know a basis of $\Bbb R^3$ don't you?).  If you want to check whether a set $\{c_1, \dots, c_n\}\subset V$ is a generating set of that space, check whether $\mathcal B \subset \operatorname{span}(c_1, \dots, c_n)$.  This shouldn't take too long in this case before you find a standard basis vector that can't be represented by your set no matter which $t$ you choose -- possibly the *first* standard basis vector will do. 

Comment: @ Bye_World, $(0, 0, 1)$ seems like a good counterexample. My problem here is that the type of algebra I did is how I usually prove a set of vectors spans some space. If this algebra allows for wrong results to slip through, then I am in trouble, right? :)

Comment: To accurately find your trouble, i.e. to show that these two vectors do **not** span $\mathbb{R}^3$, you should be asking a different question: not "how can we show that $t$ is not allowed to vary", but "how can we show that for any $t$ there exists $(x,y,z)$ such that the equations for $a,b$ are inconsistent".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, a pair of vectors $V,W$ cannot span $\mathbb{R}^3$. You ask about a specific example $V=(2,1,1)$ and $W=(2,t,2t)$. I suggest doing the calculation first for general $V,W$, then plugging in the coordinates of the $V,W$ that you want.

Or you could take a slight shortcut. Your vectors $V,W$ are always linearly independent no matter what $t$ is (if $(2,1,1)=s(2,t,2t)$ then $s=1$ but $(2,1,1) \ne (2,t,2t)$ no matter what $t$ is). So assuming $V,W$ are a linearly independent pair of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, how do we find a third vector that is not in the span of $V,W$?

Answer: the cross product $V \times W$.

To summarize, for **any** real number $t$, if $V=(2,1,1)$ and $W=(2,t,2t)$, and if $(x,y,z)=V \times W$, then your equations for $a,b$ are inconsistent.

Comment: $\vec{V} \times \vec{W}$ is clever, +1

Comment: @ Lee Mosher, for what values of $t$ are the equations inconsistent? For all $t \in \mathbb R$. How do we show that?

Comment: I added a summary addressing your comment.